# Converting datatypes in mysql

Tags: mysql

This might be a very general question but i have a doubt in this.
As a beginner I was unsuccessful in trying to insert rows into table B by selecting from table A .

A field from table A has DECIMAL datatype and its corresponding field in table B has
BIGINT datatype. Can a value with DECIMAL datatype be inserted in a field with BIGINT datatype?

Comment: Please ask one question at a time. A -1 *and* a vote to close because the title and the "question" have nothing to do in common. Consider updating one or the other.

Answer (score 0):

To my knowledge ... No ... Big int is pretty much the same as INT just that the range is higher. It takes integer values 0 to 18446744073709551615.

[More information here](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/data-type-overview.html)